# routerExtensions.navigate not working well on this NativeScript app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, nativescript, nativescript-oauth2

I have a very basic `NativeScript / Angular` project based on the sample code on:

https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth2/tree/master/demo-angular

It basically allows the user to login with `Google`.

Just after the user introduces his credentials, the user gets redirected back to the app and it should be redirected to the route: `/authenticated`.

My problem is that on the file **login.component.ts**, when `this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/authenticated"])` method is invoked, in some circumstances the user is forwarded to that route and sometimes not. I tried to investigate a bit what the circumstances are but it looks like random.

In the other hand, I have to say that I always get the access token logged on the console. So the `authService` is working fine but what it is not working fine is the navigation.

Also, I don't know if I have to use:

`this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/authenticated"])`

or

`this.routerExtensions.navigate(["../authenticated"])`

In the sample code from the official site there are two dots (second case) as you can see here:

https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth2/blob/master/demo-angular/src/app/login/login.component.ts#L23

but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

I think I'm ommitting something here.

Below you have some fragments of my code.

Any idea about how can I solve this situation?

Thanks!

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation.html#page-router-outlet -->
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { LoginComponent } from "./screens/login/login.component";
import { AuthenticatedComponent } from "./screens/authenticated/authenticated.component";
import { ItemsComponent } from "./item/items.component";
import { ItemDetailComponent } from "./item/item-detail.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
    { path: "authenticated", component: AuthenticatedComponent },
    { path: "items", component: ItemsComponent },
    { path: "item/:id", component: ItemDetailComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**login.component.html**

```
<ActionBar title="My App" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>

<StackLayout class="form">

    <Button text="Login Social Network" (tap)="onTapLogin()" class="btn btn-primary btn-active"></Button>

</StackLayout>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular";
import { ITnsOAuthTokenResult } from "nativescript-oauth2";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page/page";
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth.service";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./login.component.scss"],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private page: Page, private authService: AuthService, private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) {
    page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

    public onTapLogin() {
        this.authService
            .tnsOauthLogin("google")
            .then((result: ITnsOAuthTokenResult) => {
                console.log("back to login component with token " + result.accessToken);
                this.routerExtensions
                    .navigate(["/authenticated"])
                    .then(() => console.log("navigated to /authenticated"))
                    .catch(err => console.log("error navigating to /authenticated: " + err));
            })
            .catch(e => console.log("Error: " + e));
    }

}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import {
  TnsOAuthClient,
  ITnsOAuthTokenResult
} from "nativescript-oauth2";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private client: TnsOAuthClient = null;

  constructor() { }

  public tnsOauthLogin(providerType): Promise<ITnsOAuthTokenResult> {

    this.client = new TnsOAuthClient(providerType);

    return new Promise<ITnsOAuthTokenResult>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.client.loginWithCompletion(
        (tokenResult: ITnsOAuthTokenResult, error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error("back to main page with error: ");
            console.error(error);
            reject(error);
          } else {
            console.log("back to main page with access token: ");
            console.log(tokenResult);
            resolve(tokenResult);
          }
        }
      );
    });

  }

  public tnsOauthLogout() {
    if (this.client) {
      this.client.logout();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a sanity check, you aren't using an interceptor to handle your requests by any chance? If you do, that might be stopping the navigation action.

Comment: did you ever solve this issue? I'm having the exact same issue currently

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I think navigating direcly to `authenticated` would be correct

```
this.routerExtension.navigate('authenticated'], {
    clearHistory: true
});
```

and clearing the history after successful login.

You can also try `this.routerExtension.navigateByUrl('/authenticated')` if you prefer that.

In any case, you can quickly add some helpful tracing in your `app-routing` module:

```
NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    enableTracing: true
})
```

Lastly, sometimes it helps adding a timeout before navigating, like:

```
public onTapLogin() {
        this.authService
            .tnsOauthLogin("google")
            .then((result: ITnsOAuthTokenResult) => {
                console.log("back to login component with token " + result.accessToken);
                setTimeout( () => {
                    this.routerExtensions
                        .navigate(["/authenticated"])
                        .then(() => console.log("navigated to /authenticated"))
                        .catch(err => console.log("error navigating to /authenticated: " + err));
                }, 300);
            })
            .catch(e => console.log("Error: " + e));
    }
```

but that usually is only necessary for me when navigating while having an open modal.

*EDIT*: So, I tried your sample project and navigation after Google signing works fine for me. Since you are getting an error randomly, I guess it can only be a UI timing issue, som my last suggestion using `setTimeout` would be the proper workaround.

Comment: Which part? Removing the '/', using navigateByUrl, using a timeout, or enabling trace to get details about the issue?

Comment: I tried all of that with no success.Here you have more detailed info about the issue: https://github.com/napolev/evalproject.com-debug

Comment: So you activated router tracing and did not get anything extra in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while i used Android Emulator, i updated nativescript and changed the device used in emulator, it fixed.
so try update and some changes hope it works